# Grails Groovy - Getting min and max date for one to many relationship

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have domain classes with one to many relationship between MyClass and Event:

```
class MyClass {
  String name
  Date firstEvent
  Date lastEvent
  static hasMany = [events : Event]
}

class Event {
  String name
  Date dateCreated
  static belongsTo = [indicator : Indicator]
}
```

What is the best way to set firstEvent to reflect the min(dateCreated) and lastEvent to reflect the max(dateCreated) from the associated events?

Perhaps there's a way to access this data in a controller without having it in the domain class?

Appreciate any help. I'm new to grails :)

Comment: Create the fields as transients and use a getter instead. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19164445/74057 - it's almost exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

[namedQueries](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html) should do the trick

```
class MyClass {
  static hasMany = [events : Event]

  static namedQueries = {

    firstEvent {
      events{
        projections{
          min 'dateCreated'
        }
      }
    }

    lastEvent {
      events{
        projections{
          max 'dateCreated'
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

to call:

```
Date first = myClassIntance.firstEvent().get()
```

Comment: While this is a valid approach, this answer doesn't exactly give a full example of how it can be accomplished with a namedQuery and should be enhanced. Otherwise it's a low quality "link only" answer. You might consider giving some examples of how to solve the problem using namedQueries.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried implemented the suggestion from aldrin and it works. I may try this method too to compare :)